# MS Access: Update the parent record when a child record is saved

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I created 2 tables; Assets and AssetMovements. I also created the main Assets form and an Asset Movement form. The Asset Movement form is essentially a replica of the Assets form but it has the AssetMovements table as it's record source. I created a lookup in the AssetMovements table (AssetTag field) so a user can select an asset tag from a combo box and the details of that asset will be populated automatically into the rest of the fields on the form. The only editable fields on the form are the 'Location' and 'AssignedTo' field which refers to the employee.
Right now, everything works fine, but the problem is that if I create a new record using the AssetMovements form and save it, the 'Location' field in the original record which resides in the 'Assets" table will not be updated. Same goes for the 'AssignedTo' field in the original record.

Is there a way to update the main asset record in the Assets table whenever a new AssetMovement is created on that record?

Comment: Must you store *Location* and *AssignedTo* in the *Assets* table? Seems like you could retrieve them as needed from the latest *AssetMovement* record which matches that *AssetTag*.

Comment: Are you letting ACCESS create a blank record then filling in information?

Comment: Hello @HansUp, if I don't store them in the _Assets_ table it means that for new assets I will first have to create the main _Asset_ record, and then create an _AssetMovement_ record just to give the asset a location. Seems like it would complicate things..

Kassabba, no, no blank records.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is track the history of an Asset (where and who it belongs to). The natural way to do this is to update the Asset, and record the change in the AssetMovements table.

In many databases, you can use triggers to accomplish this. Whether you update an Asset through the UI or direct SQL queries, it never fails. However, MS Access does not have triggers per se. So you would be limited to doing so in the UI.

You could do this in the UI by adding an After Update event to the form, and the copying the changed record to AssetMovements. Not the other way around. Otherwise, in the case of a new Asset, you are creating an AssetMovement first, and then creating the Asset.

I've used HansUp's suggestion as well - i.e. just putting the location/assignment in AssetMovements, and displaying the most recent value on the form/report. What I dislike about this is that it makes the form a little more complex and if you have a lot of updates happening you could end up with a performance hit.

Then again, if your DB gets large enough that the performance hit is noticeable, you should probably be migrating the data to another kind of database anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response CodeSlave. I am trying to track the history of the assets. 

I think it would be a good idea to copy the changed records to the AssetMovements table. However, how do I set up the After update event on the Location and AssignedTo fields so that it if any of the fields is updated, the a copy of the record will be saved to the AssetMovements table?

Comment: You could set it up individually on the Location/AssignedTo fields AfterUpdate events, but that would create a record each time you changed either one of them, but before you committed the record to the database. Instead, I would add a new record into the AssetMovement table directly (through ADO or DAO) during the Form's AfterUpdate event. Right click on the box beside/above the rulers in the form, select properties, and go to the Events tab. It'll be one of the first few events in the list. Click on the ellipsis and select Code Builder. From there, it's VBA code.